# How to open a different tab in same folder using sublime text or visual studio code?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, visual-studio-code

I use sublime text 3 and visual studio code, but i found that if i open a different file in same folder , it does not open a different tab, instead the new tab will replace the old tab. How do I get a file to open in a different tab in same folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VSCode, but in Sublime, single clicking a file opens it in a `semi-transient` view for preview purposes. You can tell this is happening by the file name in the tab being *italicized*.

The reason for this is to allow you to quickly preview files for editing without having an excessive number of tabs open. So when you single click on another file, the existing preview tab is reused for the new file.

In order to commit the tab to being a "fully opened" file, you can either double click the file to tell Sublime that you want to edit it, or make a modification to the file in the buffer.

This is controlled by the setting `preview_on_click`, which is turned on by default. If you turn this off, single clicking files will not preview them, so you need to double-click files in order to open them.

Comment: yes , VSCode and Sublime is same , i guess all editor is same in this things

Answer (score 0):

In both editors, if you single click a file it remains in a single tab that is re-used by other single-clicked files. If you double click the file, it opens it in a new tab. At a glance, you'll also notice that the "single click tab" title is italicized, while the ones you double clicked are regular text.